# Can Dagger inject an abstract Activity class without injecting the child Activity class?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am trying to implement Dagger in my application and I have an instance where I need to inject a field in a class within an Activity class hierarchy but the children of this class do not need any members injected. The hierarchy looks like this:

BaseActivity -> NavigationActivity -> HomePageActivity.

I am trying to inject a field in NavigationActivity but I get the following exception from Dagger:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.quidsi.diapers.activity.HomePageActivity. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
```

My module looks like such

```
@Module(
    injects = NavigationActivity.class
)
public class GestureModule {

    @Provides
    GestureInterface provideGestureInterface() {
        return new MockDrawerGesture();
    }
}
```

Is this possible with Dagger or do I need to inject every child of NavigationActivity?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with Dagger 1. You will have to inject the subclassed activities as well. And yes, unfortunately, this means you have to add all those classes to the injects list in your GestureMmodule.

Dagger 2 is right around the corner, maybe things have changed there.

Comment: Dagger2 also requires the subclasses to be injected, but it throws a compilation error rather than a runtime error if the given `void inject(SomethingActivity somethingActivity)` is missing in your component interface methods.